# What is this "provides" syntax in this kotlin jetpack compose code sample?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

What is the "provides" syntax in this code sample and what does it do?

```
LocalContentAlpha provides ContentAlpha.medium
```

It doesn't seem to be a standard kotlin keyword and I haven't had much luck googling for queries like "kotlin provides keyword" or "jetpack compose provides".

This shows up on the [Jetpack Compose codelab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-layouts?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fcompose%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fjetpack-compose-layouts#2), full snippet below.

```
@Composable
fun PhotographerCard() {
    Column {
        Text("Alfred Sisley", fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold)
        // LocalContentAlpha is defining opacity level of its children
        CompositionLocalProvider(LocalContentAlpha provides ContentAlpha.medium) {
            Text("3 minutes ago", style = MaterialTheme.typography.body2)
        }
    }
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun PhotographerCardPreview() {
    LayoutsCodelabTheme {
        PhotographerCard()
    }
}
```

Comment: If you press CTRL+B in Android Studio on such keyword or adjacent words you will see full documentation of those. With little patience I guess there's the way to find what it does ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is an example of an [infix function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/functions.html#infix-notation):

> Functions marked with the infix keyword can also be called using the infix notation (omitting the dot and the parentheses for the call).

As seen by the existence of the `infix` keyword on the [method's documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/ProvidableCompositionLocal#provides(kotlin.Any)).

So the method *could* be called normally as `LocalContentAlpha.provides(ContentAlpha.medium)`, but the infix notation allows for those extra syntax characters to be dropped.

Comment: Great answer! Thanks! Especially helpful for Kotlin beginners like me.

Comment: It's good to know that using the infix notation is not necessary, so in case when it looks confusing you can still use the classic method calling notation. Thank you!